# Main container with Aside bar and content

Tags: html, css, containers

Please, i need some help here. 2 days i can't solve this elementary task. I'm new to the web design and may be this is easy but i just can't understand, why when i use align:left/right or position:absolute for the child divs – main div just disapaer... I want aside bar to the left, tabs under it, and the main content on the right. Please give me some advise, when i do wrong?

Here's a sample:

```
<div id="main_container">

     <aside id="aside1">
        <ul>...</ul>
     </aside>

     <div class="tabs">
        <img src="images/tab1.png"/>
     </div>

     <div id="container">
       <p>...</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#main_container {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px 0px #606060;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px 0px #606060;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px 0px #606060;
    position: relative;

}

#aside1 {
    margin: 10px 10px;
    background: #c0c0c0;
    width: 250px;
}


#container {
    width: 680px;   
}

.tabs {

}
```

I know that my Css is not finished but i just confused what should i do or use.. position, float, display...

I appriciate any advices!

Comment: Check out my jsFiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/bxa63nea/)

Answer (score 0):

`position: absolute` takes an element out of document flow.  So, as far as that container is concerned, that child element no longer exists (at least in the sense it doesn't need to reserve space for its layout).

So if all the child elements of a container are positioned as `absolute`, then that container has no space which it needs to reserve, and collapses.

One solution would be to give the container a defined height, such as `#container { height: 100vh; }` which will set the height of the container to 100% of the viewport height.

Another solution would be to use something like the [flexbox model](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Answer (score 0):

Floated/absolutely positioned containers are removed from the "flow" of a document. This means that any containers around them don't think they exist anymore and the parent containers won't expand to fit around them. If you're using floats, the way to fix this is to put an element underneath the floated elements that uses `clear: both` like this:

```
<div id="main_container">

     <aside id="aside1" style="float: left">
        <ul>...</ul>
     </aside>

     <div class="tabs">
        <img src="images/tab1.png"/>
     </div>

     <div id="container">
       <p>...</p>
     </div>
     <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

for example the CSS in a other way

```
#main_container {
    width: 500px;

}
#main {
    display:table;
}
#aside1 {
    display:table-cell;
    width: 40%;
    background-color:#faf;
}
#container {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color:#555;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

first you have to modify the structure:

```
<div id="main_container">
 <div id="main">
    <aside id="aside1">
       <ul>...</ul>
    </aside>
    <div id="container">
      <p>...</p>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div id="bottom">
    <div class="tabs">
       <img src="images/tab1.png"/>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Then the css. The divs have to be defined with display:inline;

Mike

Comment: the divs #aside1 and #container have to defined with 'display:inline'

Comment: I did this and the background of aside1 disappear. And the other thing is that width of container is lost too.  May be it's ok , but i do something wrong.

Comment: With display:inline-block it's ok.. Just now <aside> drips on the bottom side of the container, and i need to be at the top.

Comment: #main_container {
    width: 500px;
    
}
#main {
    display:table;
}
#aside1 {
    display:table-cell;
    width: 40%;
    background-color:#faf;
}
#container {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color:#555;
}

Comment: try the css I wrote - every div is displayed - example https://jsfiddle.net/9jbhadgd/2/

Comment: Thank you very much for your support, Mike! I came up with one more solution. I put the aside bar and the tabs (they should be under it) in one div, and the content in the another div. Add display: inline-block and everything got right how i want it. Thank you very much, because you showed me great solutions.